# How do I reset my PlayerPrefs Highscore when pressing on a button

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Hey Im  currently trying to reset my highscore via  a button this is my code to save the highscore:

```
       if (score > GetHighScore())
       {
           PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", score);
           Highscore.text = score.ToString();
       }
   }

   public int GetHighScore()
   {
       int i = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore");
       return i;
   }
}
```

```
And this is my code for the button but it just doesnt work
```

```
    public class resetscore : MonoBehaviour

    
{
     int reset = 0;
    public int DeleteHighscore()
    {
        int i = PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", reset);


    }

    }
```

how would I need to write this so it deletes the playerprefs for the highscore?

Comment: What part of that fails? `PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Highscore", 0);` should work if the button is being triggered.

Comment: You mean like using [`PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.DeleteAll.html) ?